# Showing a specific number of characters

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to solve this program

"Use urllib to replicate the previous exercise of

(1) retrieving the document from a URL
(2) displaying up to 3000 characters, and
(3) counting the overall number of characters in the document. Don’t

worry about the headers for this exercise, simply show the first 3000

characters of the document contents."

And here's what I've come up with, which gives me the result but I was wondering if there's a way to do it without using lists

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error


user_url = input("Enter a link: ")
if len(user_url) < 1 : user_url = 'http://data.pr4e.org/romeo-full.txt'
try :
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url)
except :
    print("Enter a proper URL", user_url)
    quit()

lst = list()
count = 0
for line in fhand :
    words = line.decode().split()
    for word in words :
        #print(word)
        for char in word :
            count = count + 1
            lst.append(char)
print(lst[:3001])
print(count)
```

Comment: Are you using Linux? Windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no accepted answer, why? There is 2 answers to "(2) displaying up to 3000 characters" and if you want get length of file  "(3) counting the overall number of characters in the document." (this is working atleast with txt documents) you can use code below.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

user_url = 'http://data.pr4e.org/romeo-full.txt'
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url)
result = fhand.read() 
print(len(result))
```

This is slightly modified ForceBru's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url)
result = fhand.read(3000) # read 3000 BYTES (since it's not specified what a 'character' is)
```

Or read everything, decode and output 3000 characters:

```
result = fhand.read().decode()[:3000] # note that whitespace is a character too
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach if you need to avoid whitespace in characters and keep only 3000 characters.

```
char_count = 30
curr_char_count = 0
complete_str = ""
for line in fhand :
    new_line = line.decode().replace(" ", "")
    if len(complete_str) + len(new_line) <= char_count:
        complete_str = complete_str + new_line
    else:
        complete_str = complete_str + new_line[:((len(complete_str)+len(new_line)) - char_count)]
        break

print complete_str
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we only need to print the full file if it's <= 3000
we can specify the length (in bytes) to be read and print.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

url = input("Type the full url you want to connect: ")
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = fhand.read()

print(content[:3001].decode().strip()) 

print("\nDocument length is {}".format(len(content)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

# ask the user for the url
user_url = input('Enter a url: ')


# urlopen() makes the connection to the webserver(HOST)
# encodes the HTTP REQUEST
# sends the HTTP REQUEST
#  it retrieves the header but keep them for us somewhere else
# returns an object that is like a filehandle
try:
    file_handle = urllib.request.urlopen(user_url)
except:
    print('Invalid URL.')
    quit()


# read each line
# lines are in bytes UTF-8
# so, we MANUALLY HAVE TO DECODE THEM TO UNICODE
data_count = 0
for line in file_handle:
    data_count += len(line)
    if data_count <= 3000:
        print(line.decode().strip())

print(data_count)
```